# Powershell script to check if boot diagnostics is enabled for an Azure VM or not

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I have a list of Virtual machines in Azure Environment, and I need to check if Boot diagnostics is enabled for these Virtual machines or not?

If enabled, the powershell script should give output in which storage account it is being saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my resource group I have 2 virtual machines where vm1 has Boot diagnostics enabled to one storage account like below:

[image]

In vm3 virtual machine boot diagnostics is not enabled like below:

[image]

To check if Boot diagnostics is enabled for these Virtual machines, make use of below script:

```c
$resourceGroupName = "YourRGName"

$vms = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    if ($vm.DiagnosticsProfile.BootDiagnostics -ne $null) {
        Write-Host "Boot diagnostics is enabled for VM '$($vm.Name)'"
        Write-Host "Boot diagnostics is using storage account: $($vm.DiagnosticsProfile.BootDiagnostics.StorageUri)"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Boot diagnostics is not enabled for VM '$($vm.Name)'"
    }
}
```

***Output***:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I got the list of VM's whose Boot Diagnostics are enabled.